# Is Git really necessary for deployment?

Tags: django, git, deployment

Disclaimer: I am a newbie to web development.

I built a program using Python, on Django framework. I am at a point where I feel ready to deploy my site, and make it go live.

After extensive research, I've noticed that every possible path to deployment requires me to use Git.

The problem is that Git is so hard to manipulate on my computer. I have the wrong version (I guess) installed, and my attempts to fix compatibility issue has been a nightmare (Im using Mac 10.7.5, and for some reason cant upgrade to newer MAC El Captain)

My question is this: Is there a way to deploy WITHOUT using Git? Evenmore, is there a way to deploy without the use of version control (I'm the only one building this site).

I just want the easiest path to deployment possible, since I am a complete newbie.

PS Please dont direct me to this link: [Is git branches necessary for a single developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367351/is-git-branches-necessary-for-a-single-developer)

my questions is about the importance of using Git altogether.

Comment: git has nothing to do with deployment, it is a source control that some providers use to retrieve the code.

Comment: it seems as though every tutorial for deployment requires the code to be pulled from a Git repo. Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: Thats a bit of a broad question... it makes sense for most because they are using git. if you're using svn then introducing git makes that harder. if you're not using source control then you may as well just scp (as well as seriously question why you're not using it)..

Comment: Even if you are the only one building your site, you **definitely should** be using version control. There's no excuse not to. But that said, there's no need to use git or any other VCS for deployment.

Comment: ok, i did not know what SVN was so now i can look into that instead of Git. Thanks for the terminology. Also, I dont know what scp stand for, but i will assume it's the same as FTP (like filezilla?) in either case, i did not think of that as an option of deployment, so thanks for advice on alternate ways to deploy!

Comment: Don't go for this "git is too hard, use svn". Since you're a beginner, it will be way more productive for your career to start and learn using git

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for the advice that you highly suggest version control. I guess knowledge of Git is highly recommended for my long-term success with web develpment :(

Comment: @pynewbee - Please continue to not think of scp/ftp as an option for deployment. I only mentioned it because some people do, these people should avoid working with me or on any project that I use. If you're struggling with the git console, try using SourceTree

Comment: thanks much for reiterating the importance of Git, and for giving another reference point that I can look into (I will definitely check out SourceTree)

Answer (score 1):

For *some* platforms, git is required for deployment. Heroku, in particular, requires git for pushing changes to a remote defined on the command `heroku create`. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#prerequisites) for more details.

In other instances, you have more options, with the caveat that you may spend a lot of time configuring a system to do so and that you may suffer from the inability to have continuous deployment without downtime.

For example, using an Amazon EC2 instance or DigitalOcean, you essentially have a bare-bones Ubuntu installation upon which you control pretty much all facets of configuration, you would be able to send files to your remote instance via SSH or using one of their clients. In this case, you would generally do the following:

- Shut down your Django server
- Backup your existing application and DB, *just in case*
- Upload the files for your updated application
- Run any manage.py commands for migrations and updates
- `pip install -r requirements.txt` to check for updated dependencies
- Start your server up again

As stated before, git is **not** required for deployment, but most Django devs would highly, highly suggest you find the root of the issue you are having with git as it helps to protect against potentially devastating problems down the line and can greatly simplify deployment when your production environment is set up correctly.

EDIT: **It's worth noting** that git can provide deployment functionality when your deployment environment is set up properly, but deployment often is too complex a task to rely on git alone. A commonly used method is to use [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/api/contrib/django.html) with a custom `fabfile` to automate deployment tasks. In tandem with git you gain version control, simplified deployment commands, and the ability to run tasks as part of your deployment.

Comment: thanks much for a very clear answer, that Git is NOT required, but highly recommended to the point where some platforms like Heroku require it.  i really appreciate it. +1 to you